# dbt - no output on variable flags.WHICH

Tags: dbt

My issue resides on the fact that when I invoke via Jinja the variable {{ flags.WHICH}} it returns no output.

I am trying to use this variable to get what type of command the DBT is running at the moment, either a run, a test, generate, etc.

I am using the version dbt 0.18.1 with the adapter SPARK

Answer (score 0):

`flags.WHICH` was not introduced until dbt 1.0. You'll have to upgrade to get that feature. [Here](https://github.com/dbt-labs/dbt-core/blob/1.0.latest/core/dbt/flags.py) is the source for the flags module, if you're interested about the flags available in your version.

Note that in jinja, referencing an undefined variable simply templates to the empty string, and does not raise an exception.